# How do I convert a string to an iCalendar(ics) object?

Tags: java, icalendar, ical4j

I have been given the task of implementing a way to convert a string received through a JSON object to an iCalendar object(ics). I found the iCal4j library and have been attempting to use that as my parser. however it seems that the CalendarBuilder takes an InputStream.

How do I proceed ?

```
String response = jsonObj.getString("icalendar");

CalendarBuilder calBuiler = new CalendarBuilder();
Calendar calendar = calBuilder.build("???");
....
```

Edit : Would this work?

```
public Calendar convertStringtoCalendar(String arg)
{
    CalendarBuilder calBuiler = new CalendarBuilder();
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(arg.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return calBuiler.build(is);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: why you don't try if this work? if the string is already the whole icalander file this should be enough, it should be a reder, not a InputStream. ``StringReader reader = new StringReader(response );`` then ``calBuilder.build(reader );``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by doing the following.

```
public static Component getCalendarEvent(String myCalendarString) 
{
    try {
        StringReader sin = new StringReader(myCalendarString);
        CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
        Calendar calendar = builder.build(sin);

        return (Component)calendar.getComponent("VEVENT");

    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try my new iCalendar API for Java called iCalendarFx.  It can parse a string into any calendar element - VCALENDAR, VEVENT, etc.

You can check it out at http://jfxtras.org/

You can download it at https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/tree/8.0/jfxtras-icalendarfx